# does magento charge transaction fees

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am new to magento, after I create my site, I want to integrate a payment gateway. My question are
1) How do I integrate payment gateway and which payment gateway should I use?
2) Can I use free version of magento for commercial purpose ?
3) After integrating the payment gateway, when customer buys a product, does magento charge transaction fees ?  (Important question)
4) How much percentage does the payment gateway(paypal or ony other) charge when customer buys a product ?

Comment: Your merchant account charges transaction fees, Magento just generates the orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. By default Magento (Community Edition) provides many popular payment methods, like: Paypal Payments Advanced (Includes Express Checkout), Paypal Payments Pro, Paypal Payments Standard, Paypal Payflow Pro, Check / Money Order, Cash on Delivery, Authorize.net etc.

You can set up any of them by logging into admin panel, go to System --> Configuration --> Payment Methods

If you want to use any custom payment methods, you can get many of them from magento connect.

1. Yes, free version of magento (Community edition) is the most popular version of Magento and has all security aspects.
2. Magento does not charge any transaction fees.
3. To know transaction fees of any payment gateway, you can refer to their official website.
   For example: For Paypal (https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/merchant-fees)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Magento is free if CE version is used so no charges.

As far as payment fee is concerned magento just provides some payment module.These payment gateway providers do charge some fee. This fee has got nothing to do with Magento, for this you need to communicate with payment gateway providers.